# how to do a sum on many ArrayLists quickly?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

In this program I have a text file with golf scores and I have added each golfers scores into an ArrayList. I need to get the sum of these scores in each ArrayList to get the total for each golfer.

```
    File golf = new File("golf.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(golf);
    int i = 0;
    int parsum = 0, golfsum1 = 0, golfsum2 = 0, golfsum3 = 0, golfsum4 = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> par = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> golfer1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> golfer2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> golfer3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> golfer4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        par.add(i, scan.nextInt());
        golfer1.add(i, scan.nextInt());
        golfer2.add(i, scan.nextInt());
        golfer3.add(i, scan.nextInt());
        golfer4.add(i, scan.nextInt());
        i++;
    }

    for (int j : par)
    {
        parsum += j;
    }

    for (int j : golfer1) 
    {
        golfsum1 += j;
    }
    for (int j : golfer2) 
    {
        golfsum2 += j;
    }
    for (int j : golfer3)
    {
        golfsum3 += j;
    }
    for (int j : golfer4)
    {
        golfsum4 += j;
    }
```

Is there anyway to do this quicker, rather than having 5 enhanced for loops

Comment: You can have a list within a list: `List<List<Integer>>`, and then nest your for loops.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File golf = new File("golf.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(golf);
int i = 0;
int parsum = 0, golfsum1 = 0, golfsum2 = 0, golfsum3 = 0, golfsum4 = 0;

ArrayList<Integer> par = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> golfer1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> golfer2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> golfer3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> golfer4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    final int parValue = scan.nextInt(),
        golfValue1 = scan.nextInt(),
        golfValue2 = scan.nextInt(),
        golfValue3 = scan.nextInt(),
        golfValue4 = scan.nextInt();

    parsum += parValue;
    golfsum1 += golfValue1;
    golfsum2 += golfValue2;
    golfsum3 += golfValue3;
    golfsum4 += golfValue4;

    par.add(i, parValue);
    golfer1.add(i, golfValue1);
    golfer2.add(i, golfValue2);
    golfer3.add(i, golfValue3);
    golfer4.add(i, golfValue4);
    i++;
}
```

This way you directly add as you scan and store them in the lists, but avoid unnecessary iterations of the list to get the totals.

Comment: I need to have the scores outputted in ArrayLists as well as have the totals

Comment: Good thought. That will work *if* the question's requirements change -- right now the question is asking how to quickly sum the scores *from* the ArrayLists. If the ArrayList's are not needed, you're in business :)

Comment: Okay so add them to the lists as well in the while loop. You don't need to reiterate the lists to get the totals. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Java 8, use the `IntStream`:

http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/

Also, consider threading each summation task, though being that it's golf scores (trivial, small task) the overhead may be cost prohibitive.

Comment: I have a solution now, but I will definitely read into this more. Thanks your for input.